# Running web-site's JavaScript functions inside phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I'am visiting certain websites with phantomjs. Is it possible to run functions from sites environment in page.evaluate method? Can you provide and example of correct usage.

Comment: Psssssst... You should try using Puppeteer instead of Phantom: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. You just call the site function inside of `page.evaluate`. Consider the example:

**example.com html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: white">
    <p>A page</p>
    <script>
    function makeRed() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PhantomJS script**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 300 };

page.open('http://example.com', function() {

    page.evaluate(function(){
        makeRed();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
          page.render('red.png');
          phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);

});
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]